# Split string at first space

Tags: c#, split

I'm trying to split a string at the first space and only keep the 2nd half. So if the input was "1. top of steel", the output would be "top of steel". I'm working with a few different examples from here and I cant get it to work. Thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: `string secondHalf = myString.Split(new char[] { ' ' }, 2)[1];` Use the Split method with a max size on the array.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

```
var myString = "1. top of steel";
var newString = myString.Remove(0, myString.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

Answer (score 26):

This is easily accomplished using `Substring`:

```
string myString = "1. top of steel";
string newString = myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(' ') + 1);
```

This will give you a new string starting after the first space.

Answer (score 5):

Just use something like following,

```
string[] stringTokens = originalString.Split(new char[] {' '}, 2, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if(stringTokens.Length >= 2)
    newString = stringTokens[1];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just do:

```
string myString = "1. top of steel"; //replace this with the input
string resultString = myString.IndexOf(' ') > -1
    ? myString.Substring(myString.IndexOf(' ') + 1)
    : myString;
```

Comment: Your splitString needs to be an array and even then this would result in `myNewString` being `top` because it would split on each space not just the first one.

Comment: You need an array to store the result of Split.  Also, this will not work correctly when the input contains more than one spaces

Comment: This code will not work, it has too many bugs. 1)splitString needs to be an array. 2) Split function needs an array as parameter. 3) If the first 2 points are ignored even then it will return only the element at 1st index and not the rest of string.

Comment: String.Split(' ') should return an array, not a string. And this example will not get you the value "top of steel" in the OP's example.

Comment: Updated, I think I was stuck in JavaScript syntax for a moment there :/